# Loading all active sessions for an specific user PHP/SQL

Tags: php, sql, session

I'm storing my session into a SQL DB. So I want to load all the active sessions for an specific user, I could just create a field into the users table with an array of sessionIds that updates each time that specific user logs in/out.(every time a session is created or destroyed)

The thing is that the data within the sessions in the DB is encrypted, so there's no way to link a session to an specific user without de-encrypting, so linking the data directly may cause security issues, if someone some how dump the users table(assuming that they can't edit it and the passwords are one-way encrypted), and relate a superUser with an active session ID they could somehow hijack it right?

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: The session's data may be encrypted, but the session ID won't be, as that's the handle (aka pointer) to let you know who they are.  You could store that handle/ID somewhere, but if you are creating a new table to store this, don't forget to store some metadata like their IP, when the session was created, when it was last accessed, these are valuable security tidbits.

PS: Don't forget you can have dozens/hundreds of people behind a NAT, all under the same IP, so don't use that as any kind of unique identifier.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying but, if I understand correctly to accomplish what I want I would have to go through all the sessions (that in theory could be thousands) and find which session belongs to who.
My point here is doing something like Facebook does, that shows you  from which devices are you logged on and let you, kick'em out

Comment: you can associate username, or userid with specific record in DB - when session is being created. That's the correct way how session should be created - after authentication process. To improve security, store user IP address as proposed by TravisO and also user agent. Consider storing also login time to properly time out session after specific inactive time, etc...